# Can't find a library to work with usrp x310 in python

Tags: python, usrp, uhd

I tried to install `uhd` and `pyuhd` but they can't be found, next I tried to install `pysdr`, it worked but I can't import that to my project. Does someone know how to work with the `usrp`?

Notice that I have already installed `uhd` and Python 3.8.5 on my computer.

When running `pip install pyuhd/uhd` I have got this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyuhd/uhd (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyuhd/uhd
```

When trying to import `pysdr` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sdr\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pysdr
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pysdr\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pysdr.gui import base_plot
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pysdr\gui.py", line 1, in <module>     
    from bokeh.plotting import Figure
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bokeh'
```

Comment: `pyuhd` and `uhd` are not pypi packages, and `pyuhd/uhd` is neither. Where did you hear about them? There is a package for [pysdr](https://pypi.org/project/pysdr/). For the last error, did you try `pip install bokeh`?

Comment: yes i did and after that i have this errorTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sdr\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pysdr
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pysdr\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pysdr.gui import base_plot
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pysdr\gui.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bokeh.plotting import Figure
ImportError: cannot import name 'Figure' from 'bokeh.plotting'. which i cant fix with pip install

Comment: Is this the library you're trying to use? [EttusResearch/uhd](https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd) - in that case they keep a python API mirror in their repository that you can clone and use: [EttusResearch/uhd/tree/master/host/python/uhd](https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd/tree/master/host/python/uhd) Installation is covered in their documentation: [Installing the Python API](https://files.ettus.com/manual/page_python.html)